# Constraint Satisfaction with Uncertainty

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, probability, constraint-satisfaction

I'm trying to solve a problem in which the satisfaction of constraints cannot always be verified. I can find lots of papers on *flexible* constraint satisfaction, but that's not quite what I want. Here's an example:

```
P(Jim likes Cheese) = 0.8
P(Joe likes Cheese) = 0.5
P(Sam likes Cheese) = 0.2
P(Jim and Sam are friends) = 0.9
P(Jim and Joe are friends) = 0.5
P(Joe and Sam are friends) = 0.7
```

Charlie is talking about two cheese-liking friends. Who is he most likely talking about?

I'm currently viewing this as a constraint satisfaction problem:

```
[likes cheese]   [likes cheese]
 |                           |
 | /-------[alldiff]-------\ |
 |/                         \|
[X]--------[friends]--------[Y]

  ?            ?             ?
  |            |             |
(Sam)        (Joe)         (Jim)
```

Are there existing ways for dealing with this type of CSP?

Is a CSP even the right way to frame the problem?

Comment: Can you assume anything about independence? I suppose in this example, you could have two friends that met at a cheese-sampling and that would throw the whole thing.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question; perhaps my example was bad though.

I want to treat a set of Predicates `P` as a set of constraints on the possible variables which can be substituted into those predicates. Unfortunately we can only evaluate whether a predicate holds on substitution with a limited degree of certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a propositional model (where each variable has a distinct name), you should have a look at *probabilistic graphical models* (in particular *Markov networks*). They are very closely related to SAT and CSP, since they are basically a generalization, but still fall into the same complexity class `#P`.

If you are interested in concise, first order representation of these models, you should look into *statistical relational learning* or *first order probabilistic models* (synonyms). Here, the model is expressed in a "lifted" form. E.g. possibly probabilistic constraints of the following form, using variables ranging over some object domain:

```
on(?x,?y) => largerThan(?y,?x)
```

Inferences with these models that do not rely on generating the ground model are done in the field of *lifted probabilistic inference*.

Comment: I've accepted that CSPs are not the right way to solve my problem, but  in the end I decided that graphical models in general were not the appropriate solution, especially because I am not trying to perform inference, but rather unification/reference resolution.

I'm accepting this answer because even though it wasn't the solution to my problem, that was a result of my problem being framed in the wrong light, and this answer was the most informative.


My problems continue here!:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090385/ai-partial-unification-in-open-world-reference-resolution

Answer (score 1):

This looks much more like [statistical relational learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_relational_learning) than constraint satisfaction. See in particular [Probabilistic logic networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_logic_network).

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is so?
There's very little information available on PLNs...

Comment: From Wikipedia: "he basic goal of PLN is to provide reasonably accurate probabilistic inference..."

This doesn't seem related to what I want. In my scenario I have a set of values. Periodically, I will get sets of predicates, and need to return a combination of these values which satisfies the set of predicates. If I were able to access discrete truth values for the variable-value substitutions it would be a straighforward CSP.
The twist is the uncertainty over substitution. 

Well, the other twist is that I'm working in an open world, but let's ignore that for now.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to infer the variable-value substitutions that maximize the likelihood of a set of conditional predicates. That's why I suggested PLNs (or some other statistical relational model). If that's not what you mean, can you be more rigorous about what constraint satisfaction means in this context? How do you know when you've achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in unification aspects of probabilistic inference, then you need to look, as pointed out by Special Touch, at statistical relational models. The most prominent in that area is Markov Logic Networks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_logic_network). The original paper even has a "friends and smokers" example very close to yours.

One way of solving MLNs and other probabilistic relational models is lifted probabilistic inference, which explicitly involves issues such as unification. Here is the link to a tutorial: https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~natarasr/tutorials/lifted.htm.
However, this is a relatively recent line of research and unlikely to be easily applicable in practice.

Another even more recent line of probabilistic relational models is probabilistic *programming* (there is a DARPA grant on the subject going on right now). You might want to check the languages Church, BLOG (Bayesian Logic) and Figaro, but again, those are recent research topics and not so easy to use.